# Configuring PhpStorm RESTful Client to work with Laravel

Tags: php, rest, laravel, phpstorm

I'm trying to build RESTful API with Laravel using PhpStorm and artisan server, but when I try to test with Rest Client I receive this error:

[image]

For now I write only the GET method and I receive correct output in my browser with the address `http://localhost:8000/users`

This is my code:

**routes.php**

```
Route::resource('users','UserController');
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    return \Response::json(User::all());
}
```

I tried also to add json in request window
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`php artisan serve --host 127.0.0.1` should do the trick.

Looks like PHPStorm does a lookup on `localhost` which results in `127.0.0.1`. But `php artisan serve` binds to your local IPv6 address `::1`.

Comment: exactly what I've being looking for